# How to add a "Add as link file" in the ProjectTemplate1.vstemplate?

Tags: .net, templates, vsix, visual-studio-extensions

I have added a class file (LocalInitializer.cs) as "Add as link file" in my Project under a folder call say "Initializer". What will I do in the ProjectTemplate1.vstemplate file to add it. The current structure is

```
<TemplateContent>
    <Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">      

      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" OpenInEditor="true">Initializer\GlobalInitializer.cs</ProjectItem>

    </Project>   
  </TemplateContent>
```

But it gives error

Could not find file 'D:\ProjectTemplate1\ProjectTemplate1\Initializer\GlobalInitializer.cs'

I even tried by adding

```
<ItemGroup>     
    <Compile Include="Initializer\GlobalInitializer.cs" />      
</ItemGroup>
```

into ProjectTemplate.csproj but same error.

any idea of how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you will need to look at as named "Custom Wizards" approach. Read these threads on VSX MSDN Forum (Visual Studio Extensibility) as a starting point:

- [c# Project template with linked file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/df624bb3-2b9b-4559-8e54-be721cefbcad/)
- [How to add a file to Visual Studio template but this file shouldn't be a part of created solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/46bc738e-a0af-48ac-941c-097bd17a0dfb)

Hope that helps